# Change js object property getter/setter

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, closures, getter-setter

Is it possible to change the value of the property getter of an object?
let's say we have

```
const autoIncrementer = (function() {
  let value = 0;

  return {
    incr() {
        value++
    },

    get value() {
        return value
    }
  };
})(); 
function anotherFunctin (){//log smth.}
autoIncrementer.value = anotherFunction;
```

P.S. I know that this does not do any good, so I just need an explanation of why is this so? and is there any way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Look into [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: I answered below. But it seems you need `setter` and auto-incremental getter. Am I right?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yeah it does the thing! thanks

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes it Absolutely does(answer my question)! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setter` along with `getter`.

```
let obj = {
  get propName() {
    // getter, the code executed on getting obj.propName
  },

  set propName(value) {
    // setter, the code executed on setting obj.propName = value
  }
};
```

About getters/setters usage - [read more here](https://javascript.info/property-accessors)